# Statistics test for paired data with discrete outcomes

Tags: t-test, discrete-data, paired-data

I have pre-post data for several variables and I'm looking to analyze them. The responses to the questions are 0,1,2,3,4 with 4 being best and 0 being worst.

For each variable could I simply find the mean of the responses and compare pre-post with the t-test? Or should I be using another test?

Comment: Is one or more of your variables a control condition of some sort.  Please provide more details in your question.

Comment: So people were asked about policies they have adopted before a training and then after a training. If they completely adopted the policy the score was 4. Each "variable" is a single question about a single policy. For now I'm just trying to determine if increases or decreases in policy adoption were significant after the training. Later I'm hoping to construct a model to see if varying levels of technical assistance affected policy change.